# Can I use certificate based encryption with Eclipse-Mosquitto and Dynamic Security plugin

Tags: ssl, plugins, mqtt, mosquitto

For context, I am using Eclipse Mosquitto broker and would like my clients to connect via TSL/SSL (so both server and client provide certificate). Also, I would like my broker configuration to be dynamic for which I would like to use dynamic-security plugin.

I've studied the dynamic-security plugin documentation and it seems to me that dynamic-security plugin does not support using certificate based encryption as there is no option besides providing username/password when creating the new client. From [here](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/1779) the command to add new client is as follows:

```
{
        "command": "addUser",
        "username": "",                 # Required
        "password": "",                 # Required, must not be empty.
        "clientid": "",                 # Optional, if empty then any client id is valid for 
                                        # this username. If not empty, then only a specific 
                                        # clientid may use this username.
        "policyName": "",               # Optional, if empty or omitted then use the default 
                                        # user policy
},
```

As can be seen the username and password are required, not optional. So seems to me that I cannot define clients which would connect using certificates. Is this correct and if not then is there somewhere documentation on how to use certifcate based authentication with dynamic-security plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean certificate based authentication when you said "certificate based encryption"

Then the following 2 configuration option will help:

- `use_subject_as_username`
- `use_identity_as_username`

These will use with the whole Subject or just the CN value of the client certificate as the username when a new client connects.

Both options are clearly explained in the `mosquitto.conf` man page available [here](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html)

You should be able also set an arbitrary password iirc

Comment: Right, but in that case will the broker look for a certifcate in the cafile and not use the password for authentication? In case I add a new user on-the-fly then how would I add the new certificate for this new user? Just update the cafile or do I need to do something extra?

Comment: You don't update the CA when adding a new user, you just always signing the new user's cert with the same CA cert.